# How to open activity from widget like this: if app is not open, open main activity too but if app is open, just open on top of the current activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-widget, android-pendingintent

Basically I want the user to be able to hit back and reach my main activity at some point. So here are the two senarios:

1. If the app is already open, then the widget will just launch the app and start the activity on top of it.
2. If the app is not open, I want the main activity to be already present in the back stack.

Is this possible? I think for senario 2 the code would look like this right:

```
Intent mainActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
mainActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); //this basically starts the app from fresh (i.e. clears current activities)

Intent addCruisesIntent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
addCruisesIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK ); //this basically starts the app from fresh (i.e. clears current activities)

Intent[] intents={mainActivityIntent,addCruisesIntent};
Intent[] intents={addCruisesIntent};

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context, 0, intents, 0);
```

I was wondering if there was a flag or a combination of flags that can achieve what i want.